# Finding indices of an array that lie inside a circle efficiently

Tags: c++, arrays

In advance I will tell you that I am starting to learn to program.

The problem is the following:

I have an array of length N and I want to find all the indices that lie inside a circle of radius R centered one index, say the jth.

I have an idea, but it might be very inefficient.

I would convert some kth index in [0,N-1] to Cartesian coordinates using:

```
        int x = k / side;               

        int y= k % side;
```

where side is sqrt(N), and test whether it satisfies the equation of the circle:

```
         (x_xC)*(x-xC)+ (y_yC)*(y-yC)<=R*R
```

where (xC, yC) are the coordinates of the jth element. If yes, I would store the index associated with (x, y) or else do it again for the next element until I cover up the whole array.

Is it a good idea or is it too inefficient for very large arrays?

Comment: You say it "might be very inefficient".   Do you have any objective justification (e.g. performance measurement, profiling) for saying "your application needs better performance than given by this approach"?   If you can't provide such a justification, look up the term "premature optimisation".

Comment: What are the elements of the array? integers? 2D points? n-dimensional vectors?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @A.S.H The elements of the array are irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: @Toby Speight It is not a code question, it is an algorithm question.

Comment: @Peter The array length would be of the order of 1e6 and therefore I was concerned about it.

Comment: @Peter and it should be done 1e8 times as part of a larger problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to loop over not the entire array, but only the elements which do lie in the circle:

1. Compute `xC` and `yC`.
2. Let `y` loop from `yC-R` to `yC+R` (with proper clipping at the array boundaries, and with proper rounding in case `R` is not an integer).
3. For each such `y`, let `r=sqrt(R*R-(y-yC)*(y-yC))` and let `x` loop from `xC-r` to `xC+r` with proper rounding (and, again, proper clipping at the array boundaries).
4. Convert `x` and `y` back to an array index.

Comment: But to loop y from yC-R to yC+R first I would have to do an array that finds out this y's, right? I would have to run a loop through the whole array to find elements such that abs(x-xC)<=R && abs(y-yC)<=R, and then I should to this that you say. To convert back to the array index I would only have to do index = side * y + x

Comment: Finding these `y`s is right there: Take all `y`s between `yC-R` and `yC+R`. (For simplicity of presentation, I'm ignoring clipping, here.) Both bounds can be calculated from the data that you already have. This can be as simple as `for y=yC-R to yC+R do ...`. (I do not know which programming language you intend to use, so syntax might vary.)